# Why VDFs need to be "quickly" verifiable?

Tags: random-number-generator, verifiability

I am very new to the topic, I found it out only today afternoon, so forgive the dumbness of the question should that be the case.

I have tried to grasp the rationale of Verifiable Delayed Functions (whatched all the videos, read all articles), used in many blockchain-related applications. I understand that the 2 properties that the functions need to fulfil are the following:

- Sequential: you cannot know the output until you first executed all the necessary steps
- Efficiently verifiable: after the function has been computed on an input `x`, it should be **fast** to verify that the output `y` came from executing the VDF on `x`

Now, the part I don't get is: why should it be **efficient**? Taking for instance the example of the Random Beacon use case:

- A,B,C,D,E submit a random value
- A random beacon has to be derived from this random value
- We need to avoid that E can manipulate the output of the random value by means of its input, brute-forcing the desired output with many inputs with its incredible parallel CPU power

If a VDF that is not efficient is used, wouldn't the conditions still be met?

- A,B,C,D,E submit random value
- E needs 1 hour to calculate each single output sequentially, so it cannot really brute force anything
- Meantime the random beacon is calculated and broadcasted
- Whoever needs to use it, will take another hour to verify it. Annoying, but still feasible.

I understand that this makes everything extremely slow, but is that the only reason to have the efficiency as a hard requirement? Or are there motivations such that the applications would be actually impaired/unsecure? I bet it's the second one, but why?

Comment: In theory, it isn't absolutely necessary that verification be fast. But the usual application is a client authenticating with a server. We *want* to impose some minimum amount of delay on the client, to make a brute-force attack thoroughly impractical. If, however, it imposes a substantial extra load on the server, system administrators (and such) are likely to reject it.

Comment: Are you saying if it takes 1 hour to construct a VDF random value and it should take 1 hour to verify the correctness of the VDF random value (proof verification)?